# vue.js - problem with getting and displaying required value from object - onclick

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been trying many things with vue.js methods, directives, various loops, and higher order functions, and tried many things with `$this.refs`...
**The goal is to display a book description when clicked on title (which is button element - vue.js template, and it's rendering works fine - displayed properly):**

```
<section  v-for="(bookTitle, index) in books"
      v-bind:key="index"
      
      >
    <button
      ref="el"
      @click="hidden = !hidden"
      class="list-group-item"
    v-if="bookTitle.title"
    >{{bookTitle.title}}
    </button></section>
```

I've fetched an API, and made a data array from its properties:

```
mounted() {
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%22coding%22", {
  method: "get",
})
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    let title;
    let description;
    let authors;
    let id;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
      title = result.items[i].volumeInfo.title;
      description = result.items[i].volumeInfo.description;
      authors = result.items[i].volumeInfo.authors;
      id = result.items[i].id;
      this.bookData.push(
      
        {
        avalable: true, 
        title,
        id
        },
        {
        authors,
        description,
        id
        }
```

Maybe, the problem is in my formulation of objects.
If there's some easy way to achieve that goal inside a vue.js project, please help.
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the bookData object have a property to show the button (showButton), and onclick of it make it false. Refer below code.

Working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g52xswbj/3/)

```
this.bookData.push(      
{
   avalable: true, 
   title,
   id,
   description,
   showButton = true
}
```

and in the template based on that either show the button or title of the book. No need to use ref element here.

```
<section  v-for="(bookTitle, index) in books"
   v-bind:key="index"
   >
   <button
      @click="bookTitle.showButton = !bookTitle.showButton"
      class="list-group-item"
      v-if="bookTitle.showButton"
      >{{bookTitle.title}}
   </button>
   
  <!-- Have the logic for title here -->
  <h2 v-if="!bookTitle.showButton">{{bookTitle.description}}</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Thx, @Sowmyadhar Gourishetty , but how can we show particular bookData.description, which is bound for the same bookTitle.title? That must be done with onclick event. That's the problem, actually.

Comment: updated the code and the live example. please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: This works really fine, dude @Sowmyadhar Gourishetty. Thank you very much. Is it possible to easy-make some kind of toggle switcher to hide those bookData.description elements when they are shown on this way?

Comment: @Milosh, Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/yLnhq89x/. I have created the toggle directly, you can include bootstrap and use the toggle from there.